# Dynamic "turn page" message on SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that most of the time renders on one page.  Sometimes however it goes over and I want to display a message at the bottom of the page to turn the page.

How do I do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 2):

Make a textbox with the text you'd like to show and then do the following:

1) Go to textboxes properties->visibility

2) Select 'Show or hide based on expression'

3) in an expression box type:

```
=Iif(Globals!TotalPages > 1, true, false)
```

EDIT: Seems like this property may be used only in header and footer, so you will have to place it there and include additional condition on which page you want to show the message, e.g.

```
=Iif(Globals!TotalPages > 1 AND Globals!PageNumber = <page on which you want the message>, true, false)
```